# Windows Metro content frame navigation and back button visibility

Tags: .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a Win Metro app that is a XAML/MonoGame hybrid game written in C# with a XAML start page that contains a frame that gets loaded with menu buttons.

After submitting this to the Win Metro store I get a test protocol back basically just containing a screen shot of the start screen of my app and says "Feature not functional" with the two buttons of the start screen circled in red. There has never been a problem using those buttons on my setup (two different Win 8 Machines + simulator).

Another strange thing is that the back button is visible, which should not be possible as I explicitly set IsEnabled of the back button to False if the frame is the start frame (originally I had the IsEnabled property binding set in XAML to *CanGoBack* of the content frame, but that did not work either).

This is the code for setting the visibility of the back button when the user navigates.

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainFrame));

        Window.Current.SizeChanged += VisualStateChanged;
        contentFrame.Navigated += contentFrame_Navigated;
    }

    void contentFrame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        ApplicationViewState visualState = ApplicationView.Value;

        VisualStateManager.GoToState((Control)e.Content, 
               visualState.ToString(), false);

        if (e.Content is MainFrame)
            backButton.IsEnabled = false;
        else
            backButton.IsEnabled = contentFrame.CanGoBack;
    }

    private void backButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        contentFrame.GoBack();
    }

    internal void GoHome()
    {
        while( contentFrame.CanGoBack )
            contentFrame.GoBack();
    }
```

GoHome() is called from the game page if a user opts to quit the game there (I don't get to see any back button in the start page from there either):

```
    private void QuitGame(IUICommand command)
    {
        App.ClearGame();

        Window.Current.Content = App.MainPage;
        Window.Current.Activate();
        App.MainPage.GoHome();
    }
```

And here is the code for the buttons in the MainFrame:

```
    private void onePlayerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(OnePlayerFrame));
    }

    private void twoPlayersButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(TwoPlayersFrame));
    }
```

So my question is: can the visibility of the back button be handled differently on a Surface device compared to on a Desktop PC, or how can the tester otherwise get a screen shot where the back button is visible? And - do any of you have similar experiences when submitting apps to the Windows Metro store?

I really wish Microsoft would give more detail in the test protocol, it would save time for everyone in the long run...

Comment: Could there be any swipe gestures that can go back and bypass your "first frame" check?

Comment: I am limited to the simulator, but I can not get it to go back by swiping. As I use standard code for the back button and content frame navigation, I think a lot of other apps would also get rejected for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [blog post series on common Windows Store certification failures and how to fix them](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2012/11/12/common-certification-errors-when-submitting-to-the-windows-store.aspx) that might help.  Specifically, check out the article on ["App must be fully functional"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2012/11/13/common-windows-store-certification-errors-1-2-app-must-be-fully-functional.aspx).  The main issues that cause this failure at a high level are:

- Appearing Unfinished
- Missing/Broken Functionality
- Not Providing Enough Information

In your scenario, what may have happened is that the tester navigated to another page and then came back to your home/start page (and the back button appeared to navigate backwards to whatever subpage they were on)....depends on how you implemented the back button, of course.

Can you give more detail on what the two buttons of the start screen circled in red do, or a sample of the code in their click handlers?

Comment: Looks like a very good resource, thanks. I have updated my original post with the info you requested.

Comment: Thanks, Jennifer. Have you seen this blog entry? http://themissingbit.blogspot.be/2012/10/windows-8-doesnt-want-your-app-try.html?m=1

Comment: Jennifer: As a developer who is well versed in the Microsoft stack, I really want Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 to succeed. So anything that you and other Microsofties can do to help people pass App Store validation will go a long way.

Comment: Also, while you're here: Jennifer - Are there any plans to bring back the .NET stack on either "Code Blue" or Windows 9? I just heard that Steven Sinofsky insisted that most of .NET be excluded from Windows 8 development. Sinofsky forced Windows 8 to use a completely different paradigm which favors JavaScript and HTML! What a shocking turn of events! Now, ironically, Xamarin tools make it easier to use .NET to develop for iOS and Android than it is to develop for Windows 8!

Comment: Could this discussion perhaps be taken in another thread, it seems quite off topic from my question?

Answer (score 0):

Downvote with no explanation? At least clarify what is not useful with the question...

Anyway, I thought I'd follow up with what finally got the app working if others are facing similar problems.

I made two changes before making the submit that got the app through certification:
I changed the order of

```
 contentFrame.Navigated += contentFrame_Navigated;
```

and

```
 contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainFrame));
```

(so it is like the above, which means that backButton.IsEnabled explicitly is set to false at startup in the event handler)

I also removed a call to

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("startuplog.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

in App.xaml.cs that was left behind when I was debugging to get it through WACK locally.

After these changes it worked.